# BST node insertion failing in python implementation

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

The resulting BST does not get updated on insertion of new values. For children nodes who are empty, this code finds the appropriate position but fails to update the inserted value. Any insight, please. Thanks.

```
class Node:
  def __init__(self, val):
    self.val = val
    self.left = self.right = None

def insertbst(root, val):
    if root == None:
       root = Node(val)
       return 
    if val <= root.val:
      insertbst(root.left, val)
    elif val > root.val:
      insertbst(root.right, val)

def display(root):
  if root == None: return
  display(root.left)
  print root.val
  display(root.right)  

if __name__ == "__main__":
  root = Node(100)
  insertbst(root, 20)
  insertbst(root, 500)
  insertbst(root, 10)
  insertbst(root, 30)
```

insertbst(root, 40)
  display(root)

Comment: https://gist.github.com/jakemmarsh/8273963

Answer (score 0):

You did not connect the nodes at all. See the code below. When a node is created, it is not connected to any other nodes.

```
def insertbst(root, val):
   if root == None:
      root = Node(val)
      return
```

You can connect two node by

```
node_A.left = node_B
# generates
    node_A
    /
node_B

node_A.right = node_B   
# generates
    node_A
          \
          node_B
```